# My Withdraw function doesnt work

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm writing my first contract and my withdraw function doesnt work. Eth doesnt move to my _withdrawAddr.

Also can somebody explain why my function getBalanceThis returns 0 instead of amount I send to contract and my other GETTER functions getBalanceOwner, getBalanceBuyer and getBalanceWithdrawAddr all return value..

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test{

    address payable owner;
    address payable buyerAddr;
    address payable withdrawAddr;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    constructor(address payable _buyerAddr, address payable _withdrawAddr) payable public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        buyerAddr = _buyerAddr;
        withdrawAddr = _withdrawAddr;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyBuyer(){
        require(msg.sender == buyerAddr);
        _;
    }

    function Send() payable public onlyBuyer{
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function getBalanceOwner() view public returns(uint){
        return owner.balance;
    }

    function getBalanceBuyer() view public returns(uint){
        return buyerAddr.balance;
    }

    function getBalanceWithdrawAddr() view public returns(uint){
        return withdrawAddr.balance;
    }

    function getBalanceThis() view public returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function Withdraw() onlyOwner public returns(bool success)  {
        uint wd = 5 ether;
        withdrawAddr.transfer(wd);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ether doesn't move in your `Withdraw()` function because you do the transfer in the `Send()` function, so there is no ether to transfer. For that reason there is no ether in the contract, so the function `getBalanceThis()` will return 0.

Alternative solution:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test{

    address payable owner;
    address payable buyerAddr;
    address payable withdrawAddr;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    constructor(address payable _buyerAddr, address payable _withdrawAddr) payable public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        buyerAddr = _buyerAddr;
        withdrawAddr = _withdrawAddr;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyBuyer(){
        require(msg.sender == buyerAddr);
        _;
    }

    function Send() payable public onlyBuyer{
    }

    function getBalanceOwner() view public returns(uint){
        return owner.balance;
    }

    function getBalanceBuyer() view public returns(uint){
        return buyerAddr.balance;
    }

    function getBalanceWithdrawAddr() view public returns(uint){
        return withdrawAddr.balance;
    }

    function getBalanceThis() view public returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function Withdraw() onlyOwner public returns(bool success)  {
        uint256 amount = address(this).balance;
        withdrawAddr.transfer(amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh well apparently I got this all wrong. I see what I did there. I thought I was supposed to send the ether to contract with transfer but transfer is the function to send the money out of contract to address. Thank you for help.